# Maven Guava missing method Sets.symmetricDifference

Tags: java, maven, guava

I have a very strange problem. I added the following dependency to my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>31.0.1-jre</version>
</dependency>
```

When I try to call write the following code:

```
import com.google.common.collect.Sets;

Sets.symmetricDifference(currentSet, referencedSet);
```

My compiler says: Cannot resolve method 'symmetricDifference' in 'Sets'

Yet I know that this method exists, I even found it in google's [repository](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/Sets.java)

Does anyone understand why this might happen? I also tried different guava versions, but nothing seems to help.

**Edit**
Error message when executing mvn install:

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /C:/somePath/backend/src/main/java/someOtherPath/service/DataVerificationServiceImpl.java:[58,76] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method symmetricDifference(java.util.Set<org.springframework.data.util.Pair<java.time.ZonedDateTime,java.time.ZonedDateTime>>,java.util.Set<org.springframework.data.util.Pair<java.time.ZonedDateTime,java.time.ZonedDateTime>>)
  location: class com.google.common.collect.Sets
```

Edit 2:

Full pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.5</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>my_project</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>My project</name>
    <description>My Project Description</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <keycloak.version>15.0.0</keycloak.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <!-- Spring boot -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.20</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.3</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.7.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.7.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>31.0.1-jre</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.keycloak.bom</groupId>
                <artifactId>keycloak-adapter-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <finalName>application</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <layers>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </layers>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
                <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <apiDocsUrl>http://localhost:8080/v3/api-docs</apiDocsUrl>
                    <outputFileName>swagger.json</outputFileName>
                    <outputDir>srcrces</outputDir>
                    <skip>false</skip>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>integration-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: You are sure you imported the corect Sets class?

Comment: Yes, just added the import statement to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The imports and usage of the library is correct.
The version also includes the method that you want, I've just checked.

This indicates that the compiler is unable to locate the relevant `jar` on the classpath.

Can you please run `mvn install` and if it reports any errors add them to the original post and also add a comment here to notify me.

**EDIT**:

The “cannot find symbol” error comes up mainly when we try to use a variable that is not defined or declared in our program.

When our code compiles, the compiler needs to verify all identifiers we have. The error “cannot find symbol” means we're referring to something that the compiler doesn't know about.

As it turns out, in your case it is a dependency version conflict which can be detected and resolved like this https://pretagteam.com/question/conflicting-library-version-in-a-java-maven-project

Comment: Hi, I added the output. If I comment the line out, everything works fine

Comment: Can you upload your project to Github ?

Comment: Also, what happens if you try to use another method from Guava ?

Comment: Can you also add your pom.xml and how you are trying to build the project ?

Comment: If I use any other method from guava everything is fine. I "solved" the problem by switching to the apache commons lilbrary. It is realy strange since it really only concerns this one method

Comment: This is really weird.

Comment: The method is also missing in the downloaded sources. I also tried restarting my IDE, nothing worked

Comment: Ahhh !! Try looking at the dependency tree. I've noticed you have quiet a big pom.xml, so probably one of the dependencies or transitive dependencies has a dependency on some super early version of Guava, and this one is loaded first. This is why you cannot see the method in there

Comment: Can you upload the project to GitHub ?

Comment: https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.javaadvent.com/2020/12/how-to-debug-dependency-conflicts-in-maven-and-gradle.html/amp here is basically how you approach problems of this kind ... mvn dependency:tree is your friend

Comment: Also this https://pretagteam.com/question/conflicting-library-version-in-a-java-maven-project

Comment: Thank you for your help. It really was a dependency conflict

Comment: Any time, bro ;)